# Any suggestions for a rapid publish journal in material science?

Tags: publications, peer-review, journals, chemistry

I am looking for a rapid publish journal in material science, environmental science or electrochemical science, open access journals are OK.

This is so weired that my defense committee requires me 3~4 papers to pass the oral defense. Though I've already had one medium and one high impact factor papers.

There's no requirements for the journal. I have 2 low quality papers, I thought I could work with others to improve their quality for better publication after I graduate, followed my supervisors' advice .

However, I need to graduate ASAP since my scholarship had already been ended.

Just looking for a rapid and easy journal in material science, environmental science or electrochemical science to publish my paper ASAP, no specific requirement is needed, I can pay that money.

Thanks.

Comment: Sorry to hear you're in that situation, and really unfortunate that the requirement wasn't communicated earlier. However, these kind of ["shopping questions"](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3657/17254) are considered off-topic here, so your question will likely be closed soon. You may want to have a look at [SciRev](https://scirev.org/) instead, to get an idea of turnaround times for different journals.

Comment: This explains the demand for predatory publishers. But I hesitate to recommend them. Whatever you do, make sure that your supervisor) graduation committee is ok with the journal you choose.

Answer (score 1):

It seems if there literally is no requirement about the journal then you can create your own journal and publish those papers yourself.